# Spring Boot: spring.profiles.active=dev/test/prod

Tags: java, spring

I wonder, in Spring Boot these profiles (test, dev, prod) are kinda **predefined**? If so, where can I see the exact settings for them? Documentation is silent about it.
The reason I feel them to be predefined is a strange behavior when I set my profiles in application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=test, h2

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none

#LOGGING
logging.level.root=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.datasource=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
logging.level.org.hibernate=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=DEBUG
```

application-h2.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:myProject;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=rat
spring.datasource.password=8965yUe4
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=embedded
```

This all works fine, as I expect, but once I erase test from this line, no logging occurs.

> spring.profiles.active=h2

This variation also works fine:

> spring.profiles.active=dev, h2

Why is that? Profiles "test" and "dev" are not mine for sure)
Thank you.

**EDIT**

I am doing this test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace= AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void findAllTest() throws Exception {
        final String[] activeProfiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();
        System.out.println("Profiles of mine ::");
        for (String activeProfile : activeProfiles) {
            System.out.println(activeProfile);
        }
        Assert.assertTrue(!userRepository.findAll().isEmpty());
        System.out.println(userRepository.findById(1L));
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no predefined profiles nor settings. There is, as of Spring Boot 2.1 I believe, a test profile usable for testing, which might enable some additional logging.

Comment: Where can I see this test profile if it silently exists? I am on Spring Boot 2.0.2

Comment: There is no profile... There has been a discussion about enabling a `test` profile when running tests such that when supplying an `application-test.properties` it would automatically be loaded without the hassle of enabling the test profile yourself (for each test).

Comment: Resolved, I had logback-spring.xml defined in project resource folder, not in test resourse folder. It somehow affected my test...

Comment: -- I do think there are predefined profiles, eg: `native` in Config Server
>> Quote:
>> 2.1.3 File System Backend
>> There is also a “native” profile in the Config Server 
>> that does not use Git 
>> but loads the config files from the local classpath or file system 
>>   (any static URL you want to point to with `spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations`). 
>> To use the native profile, launch the Config Server with `spring.profiles.active=native`.
>> https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, Boot has the possibility to define profile-specific logging in logback-spring.xml

```
<springProfile name="dev, test">
    <!-- configuration to be enabled when the "dev" or "staging" profiles are active -->
</springProfile>
```

> The  tag lets you optionally include or exclude
>   sections of configuration based on the active Spring profiles. Profile
>   sections are supported anywhere within the  element.
>   Use the name attribute to specify which profile accepts the
>   configuration.
>   [doc](http://[https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html][1])

Even with file location in main/resources **still affects test configuration** defined for a given profile in a dedicated test application-{profile}.properties located in test/resources. Practically, if I do not have any logging setting for a current test profile, in logback-spring.xml, I cannot expect logging settings defined in properties file to override it or add. Again, either not documented or not on the surface and I simply failed to find in Spring Boot documentation.

I had this file with similar  sections, where I defined loggers for certain profiles: test and dev and prod. But I never created these profiles manually. Seemingly, Boot crates them automatically.. or does some other magic known only to itself, never documented.

So what I did to resolve is to make profiles name defined in logback-spring.xml 
match those defined in application-{profile}.properties, putting all the logic to represent logging to xml-file. Namely:

```
<springProfile name="h2">
</springProfile>
```

matches

```
application-h2.properties
```

making properties files free from logging logic.

Hope it could help someone.

Answer (score 2):

If you load a specific profile which does not exist, Spring falls back to the default profile and loads the values from the `application.properties` file.

In your case (`spring.profiles.active=dev, h2`) Spring could not find the dev profile, loads the values from the `application.properties` *and* the `application-h2.properties`

So if you now load only the `h2` profile spring loads only the values from the `application-h2.properties` file.

Comment: If I put all logging settings to h2 profile, still no result, no logging at all (with spring.profiles.active=h2)! But, as soon as I add spring.profiles.active=test, h2 logging magically occurs.

Comment: Have you tried to start the application and load the profile with a JVM property?

Comment: Yep, I did, no result. I am actually doing tests, I edited the post and included the test case.

Comment: Resolved, I had logback-spring.xml defined in project resource folder, not in test resourse folder. It somehow affected my test...